# How can I minus the quantity from list table in VueJS?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

Good day everyone! Can you help me how can I minus the quantity of list table by using the quantity of cart table? In my console.log when I add more than one item to the cart and click the minus button the quantity of each row are the become the same. The quantity from the list table are not the same. How can I get the right result of each quantity in my cart table? I want to display the right answer in the bottom of the cart table. Here’s my jsfiddle --> 
https://jsfiddle.net/2zx9vy3n/20/

```
minusFromListToCart : function() {
            for(var index = 0; index < this.selects.length; index++) {
                    this.total = parseInt(this.select_quantity) - parseInt(this.input_quantity);
                console.log(this.total);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate your try, but unfortunately there are many small mistakes, like

1. repeating same product goes separately instead adding to previous,
2. you need computed method to get remaining counts
3. reset you count for next product adding in cart
4. minus quantity from relative product count instantly.

Note : add all validation like what if there is not product available etc.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selects: [],
      carts : [{
       id: null, name: null, cat: null, quantity : null
      }],
      lists: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Book', cat: 'Category 1', quantity : 50},
          { id: 2, name: 'Notebook', cat: 'Category 2', quantity : 60},
          { id: 3, name: 'Pencil', cat: 'Category 3', quantity : 70}
       ],
       select_id : "",
       select_name : "",
       select_cat : "",
       input_quantity : "",
       select_quantity : "",
       total : 0
    },
      computed:{
        remainingQuantity : function() {
          var total_qty = 0;
          var selected_qty = 0;
          for(let i in this.lists){
           total_qty += this.lists[i].quantity;
          }
          return total_qty;
   }
      },
    methods : {
     retrieveList : function(id, name, cat, quantity) {
      this.input_quantity =1;
          this.select_id = id;
      this.select_name = name;
      this.select_cat = cat;
      this.select_quantity = quantity;

      //console.log(this.select_quantity);
      
      
     },
     addToCart : function() {
          if(!this.input_quantity){
            return false;
          }
      this.carts.id = this.select_id;
      this.carts.name = this.select_name;
      this.carts.cat = this.select_cat;
      this.carts.quantity = parseInt(this.input_quantity);

      console.log(this.carts.quantity);
          
            var selected_index =  this.selects.map((e)=>e.id).indexOf(this.select_id);
            if(selected_index > -1){
           this.selects[selected_index].quantity += parseInt(this.input_quantity);
            }else{
            this.selects.push({...this.carts});
           }
            
            var lists_index =  this.lists.map((e)=>e.id).indexOf(this.select_id);
            if(lists_index > -1){
              this.lists[lists_index].quantity -= parseInt(this.input_quantity);
            }
      
     }

     
  }
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">
  <table border="1">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Category</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(list, index) in lists">
     <td>{{list.id}}</td>
     <td>{{list.name}}</td>
     <td>{{list.cat}}</td>
     <td>{{list.quantity}}</td>
     <td>
      <button @click="retrieveList(list.id, list.name, list.cat, list.quantity)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to cart</button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="1" class="mt-4">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Category</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(select, index) in selects">
     <td>{{select.id}}</td>
     <td>{{select.name}}</td>
     <td>{{select.cat}}</td>
     <td>{{select.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>Final Quantity : {{remainingQuantity}}</p>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" class="text-dark" tabindex="1">   
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add Transaction</h4>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>

            
      <div class="modal-body mx-auto" id="modal-less-input">
       <label for="input_quantity">Quantity</label>
       <div class="input-group form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control col-sm-12" id="input_quantity" v-model="input_quantity" name="input_quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" autofocus required>
       </div> 
       
      </div>
        
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button @click.prevent="addToCart()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="far fa-save">&nbsp;</i> Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
     
        </div>
     </div> 
   </div>
 </div>



 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```